# Check if optional array is empty in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type, is-empty

I realize there are a ton of questions on SO with answers about this but for some reason, I can't get any to work. All I want to do is test if an array has at least one member. For some reason, Apple has made this complicated in Swift, unlike Objective-C where you just tested if `count>=1`. The code crashes when the array is empty.

Here is my code:

```
let quotearray = myquotations?.quotations

if (quotearray?.isEmpty == false) {

let item = quotearray[ Int(arc4random_uniform( UInt32(quotearray.count))) ] //ERROR HERE

}
```

However, I get an error:

`Value of optional type '[myChatVC.Quotation]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type '[myChatVC.Quotation]'.`

Neither of the fix-it options to chain or force unwrap solve the error. I have also tried:

```
if array != nil && array!. count > 0  and if let thearray = quotearray
```

but neither of those will work either

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could unwrap the optional array and use that like this, also use the new `Int.random(in:)` syntax for generating random `Int`s:

```
if let unwrappedArray = quotearray,
    !unwrappedArray.isEmpty {
    let item = unwrappedArray[Int.random(in: 0..<unwrappedArray.count)]
}
```

Comment: Using if let and isEmpty together looks like a good way to test for an optional array having an element

Comment: There is always room for improvement. Just like making the bool check shorter as I just did with `unwrappedArray.isEmpty == false` statement or calling randomElement on array directly.

Answer (score 3):

`randomElement` already exists, so don't reinvent the wheel:

```
var pepBoys: [String]? = ["manny", "moe", "jack"]
// ... imagine pepBoys might get set to nil or an empty array here ...
if let randomPepBoy = pepBoys?.randomElement() {
    print(randomPepBoy)
}
```

The `if let` will fail safely if `pepBoys` is `nil` or empty.

Comment: This code worked as well. Marking it correct as this version is slightly shorter than @Frankenstein's which also worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use guard statement

```
guard let array = optionalArray, !array.isEmpty else { return }
```

Answer (score 0):

check the first element is exist or not

```swift
var arr: [Int]? = [1, 2, 3, 4]
if let el = arr?.first{
  print(el)
}
```